# Example of function prototype scope

Tags: c++, function, scope, declaration, function-declaration

There is a definition of function prototype scope (3.3.4/1 N3797):

> In a function declaration, or in any function declarator except the
>   declarator of a function definition (8.4), names of parameters (if
>   supplied) have function prototype scope, which terminates at the end
>   of the nearest enclosing function declarator.

Can we get an example described that rule?

Comment: Not sure what example you're looking for. A function declaration is a very simple construct. The function prototype scope means that those parameters are visible until the function declaration can be considered closed (hopefully I am not misconstruing the standard). That means, for example, that you cannot have two parameters with the same name.

Comment: @AndreaLaforgia I'm looking for example clearly showing the scope.

Comment: @AndreaLaforgia This question is a perfect example of how the standard can complicate even the most simple of concepts.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv You should really update your profile saying that you are making a c++ compiler

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simple example

```
int a;

void f( int a, int a );
```

The compiler will issue an error for the second parameter `a` because its name coincides with the name of the first parameter. That is the compiler will report that there is a redefinition of the name `a`. The same name is defined twice in the same scope.

Or another example

```
struct A {};

void f( int A, struct A );
```

The first parameter name hides the structure name so the second parameter is defined using the elaborated name of the structure.

Comment: I think the first int a; in your example can be misleading. In order for the compiler to report a duplicate name in the prototype, you don't need to declare that variable.

Comment: @Andrea Laforgia  This shows that function prototypes have their own declaration regions and a name in a function prototype can hide a name in the outer declaration region. It would be better if I used the first object as a default argument of the function. But I had no much time that to write a vary detailed answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example that involves a relatively rare, but sometimes encountered mistake

```
void foo(struct S *v);

struct S {
  int i;
};

int main() {
  struct S *p = 0;
  foo(p);           // ERROR: incompatible pointer types
}
```

The above code is ill-formed (to borrow a C++ term), because `struct S` is not yet known at the point of declaration of `foo`. For this reason `struct S` inside the prototype of `foo` is interpreted as a forward declaration of a new type. It has *function prototype scope*. It goes out of scope once the prototype ends. This means that declaration of `struct S` inside the `foo`'s prototype is completely unrelated to the declaration of `struct S` that follows it. These are two different types. Pointer `p` inside `main` is not compatible to the parameter type of `foo`. The code is ill-formed.

Note that if you swap the declaration of `struct S` and the prototype of `foo`, the declaration of `struct S` inside thew prototype is no longer a forward declaration. It is assumed to refer to the previously declared `struct S`. The code becomes correct.